# Deformed geometry on render

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, geometry

I'm new to Blender and I've been following the "How to Make Interiors in Blender (Tutorial)" by Blender Guru and everything was alright up until some point (which I didn't realize in time) where basically, in viewport shading, my room is alright and then in render, it's looks like my room suffered a nuclear earthquake.

What is happening? Can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Viewport shading/Nuclear Earthquake]

Comment: Ah I see the problem, looks like you may have a modifier that is still active in your render, perhaps a subdivision surface set to 2 in render and 1 in viewport.

Comment: @NascentSpace I don't see a modifier on this object on the Modifier Properties panel. could this be anywhere else?

Comment: Consider uploading your blend file, and I'll analyse it for a solution https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I tried uploading on blend-exchange 3 times and it kept crashing, so I hope you'll find this wetransfer link acceptable: https://we.tl/t-XblwuMYGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][image]The problem is very simple. The displacement in the materials you have given the base mesh of the room destroys your mesh. delete it, and the problem is resolved.[image]

Comment: it worked! thank you so much. why do you think it happened? shouldn't I be able to apply displacement?

Comment: You can either delete the displacement because you already have a normal map on your materials, or either you can connect the normal map into the normal input of a bump node and connect the displacement map in the height input. Then decreas the distance in the bump node to something suitable. The way you did it is heavily displacing the entire mesh.